# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on ABAddressBookSave

Tags: ios, iphone, exc-bad-access, addressbook

I am using below code to remove the contact from my addressbook. (on iOS 5.0). But its giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS every time on  `ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, NULL);`. I have selected NSZombieEnalbeld but it's still not giving me clear error.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
 CFErrorRef error = NULL;

 ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook);

 BOOL success = ABAddressBookRemoveRecord(addressBook, person, &error);

 if (success)
 {
     BOOL su = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, NULL);
     NSLog(@"Removed ----");
 }
 CFRelease(addressBook);
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook);
```

[`ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABSourceRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html) returns an `CFArray` and **not** an `ABRecord`

If you want to remove a person from the address book, you need to get it's reference like:

```
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, recordID);
```

where recordID, the id of the person you are trying to remove (you need to obtain this).

As for more information on how to get a person from the address book, you can take a look [at this SO response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627147/312312)